# How do I prevent Delphi XE4 from trying to load CodeSite?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

Seems I some day removed Codesite, but Delphi XE4 continues to try load it and therefore halts during startup

- I have deleted CodeSite.
- Searched registry.
- Searched packages

Comment: "I have deleted CodeSi[t]e" ... Did you "delete" it, or "uninstall" it? Because you should **never** delete programs by simply deleting the files. **always** run the uninstaller provided with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the registry under

HKCU\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\11.0\Experts

you should find entries including

`Beyond Compare IDE Package`

and

`CodeSiteRADStudioTools`

Delete the CodeSite one (after backing up your registry of course) and the IDE will no longer attempt to use it.